# Can the iPod touch work without a battery?

Tags: ipod-touch, usb

If you were to remove the battery from an iPod touch, and then connect it to a computer, would you still be able to play music on it?

Comment: Let me guess. You have a dead battery on your iPod and want to de-brickify it without replacing the battery?

Comment: @awakeFromNib I've tried to clarify the question to make it less generic. It would probably be helpful if you could update your question to explain *why* you want to do this. Is @JohnFx's guess right?

Answer (score 5):

Probably not - In general, iPod & iPhone devices won't be usable when connected to a computer because they are trying to sync with the computer.

Instead, try getting an external speaker dock of some sort and drop the iPod into that. It's designed to power the iPod while playing.

I'm certain that this will work in the case of a dead battery. In the case of the battery actually being removed, there's a small chance that the iPod's on-board electronics will not work correctly, even if externally powered. This isn't likely, but it's possible that without a battery, the charging circuit will cause something else to go wrong. Again, not likely, but not impossible.

If you have a device with a dead battery, and you don't want to replace the battery, just leave it in there, drop it in a dock and play on.

Comment: +1 I do exactly this with an old iPod nano. Its battery life is measured in minutes, but its been sat happily in a dock pumping out noise for months without issue.

Comment: Yea, I have an old 3rd iPod more or less permanently attached to my car fro the same reason.